# Problem with publishing in multiple module project in gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-plugin

**Project Structure**
root_project : **user**
sub_project : **auth**, **resource**.
sub_project: "**auth**" depend on "**resource**".
How to publish resource first in maven local & how to use its dependency in **auth**.
There are three build.gradle present in each project i.e **user**, **auth**, **resource**.
I need to build the whole project from the root project i.e **user**
Similar question is also asked here, but its not solve my problem :https://discuss.gradle.org/t/howto-control-build-order-of-gradle-subprojects-submodules/26762

Comment: see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:declaring_project_dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gradle you don't need to publish artifacts into `~/.m2` to use them in the same project. Just use cross-project dependencies:

*`user/settings.gradle:`*

```
…
inlcude(":auth")
inlcude(":resource")
…
```

*`auth/build.gradle:`*

```
…
dependencies {
    implementation project(":resource")
}
…
```